# How to relate cloudstack volume ID to guest virtual block device ID?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virtual-disk, cloudstack

Under CloudStack 4.2.1, I have an Ubuntu 14.04 guest with 3 attached volumes of the same size.

From the CloudStack management page, I can see that each attached volume has a name and an ID (and a probably irrelevant VM ID).  By name: DATA-4113, DATA-4124 and DATA-3185

From the Ubuntu guest's command line I can use `print all` of ***parted*** to see details of the three as: /dev/vdb, /dev/vdc and /dev/vdd.

I want to detach just one of them -- /dev/vdb.  But which one is it?
Is  it DATA-4113, DATA-4124 or DATA-3185 ?

How can I relate external identifiers with internal device identifiers?

I am using a CloudStack account at a 3rd party hosting service (iwStack.com) so not everything is under my control.